# How to append text into an existing file using java 1.4

Tags: java, class, append, ewon

I want to append into the existing text file. For that I have tried all this in plenty of way `FileWriter`,`BufferedWriter`,`PrintWriter`,`RandomAccessFile`,`OutputStream`,`FileOutputStream`,`PrintStream` but I can't get my desired output.

This error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: could not open file '//file:/usr/backupdata/5605.txt' using mode 'a+'` sucks. (I am working with ewon flexy hardware which supports javaetk 1.4 only)

Comment: This file not found means your program is not able to find the file. this path is wrong. It has no other meanings.

Comment: Path is right and file is there too! I guess there is some problem with that mode 'a+' @muasif80

Comment: No. This exception means only and only one thing the file is not present on the specified path. I don't have any other meanings for it in my knowledge.

Comment: May be your path construction is wrong the file might be on this path but still the path syntax can be wrong.

Comment: Just verify that this path construction is correct

Comment: Show us your code; preferably in a MCVE.

Comment: My files are on ftp server, so `file:////usr/backupdata/5605.txt` is the way to write the class path right? In class 'FileConnection` I use the same method and it works! @muasif80

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a url as a file name. That won’t work.

Use

```
/use/backupdata/5605.txt
```

as the file name.